# Double SQL Query in vb.net MySQLDataAdapter

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I can't figure out why this line doesn't return anything in DataGrid, while when I use one SQL query (not double SELECT) it works fine:

```
Dim DataAdapterInb As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * From inbox WHERE receiverid='" & ID & "') LIMIT 0,5;", MySqlConnection)
```

Comment: What is the value of "ID" and do you have rows in the 'inbox' table that have an 'recieverID' field with values that are equal to 'ID'?

Comment: That part is working when I put a simple SQL, the ID is just the id of user, it's something completely assured of being working.

Comment: Can you post more code, for example, the code that represents your statements to update the DataGrid? This one line only represents the query, not anything involved in updating the DataGrid.

Comment: I just posted this because when I edit this to be Dim DataAdapterInb As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From inbox WHERE receiverid='" & ID & "';", MySqlConnection) everything works fine, I have another 5 datagrids working fine exactly like this with one simple sql query, but when using select into a select it shows nothing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the Updated Answer.

```
Dim DataAdapterInb As New MySqlDataAdapter
("SELECT t.* FROM 
       //^Changed
(SELECT * From inbox WHERE receiverid='" & ID & "')t
LIMIT 0,5;", MySqlConnection)                    //^Changed
```